# converting a chararcter to \uxxx format in C /C++

Tags: c++, c, unicode

I want to convert a string/char to \uxxx format in C / C++ program.
Support I have a Character 'A', I want to print convert as \u0041( a standard unicode ).

Second thing is I was using  a unix command utility to print (printf) to print a \uxxx string tto char.  I tried with "\u092b" it print a different character than my font file. Can any one please explain reason behind this.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: What internal format are you using to represent the characters inside the program? ASCII/UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-32/CP1490/ISO8859-1? Does The \u format support only 4 hex digits or 6hex digits. If it only supports 4 then you will need to encode as UTF-16 (as you can represent all the code points with 4 hex digits) and use surogate pairs for longer characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function using standard C++ to do this (though depending on `CharT` it may have some requirements that some valid implementation defined behavior doesn't meet).

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

template<typename CharT,typename traits,typename allocator>
std::basic_string<CharT,traits,allocator>
to_uescapes(std::basic_string<CharT,traits,allocator> const &input)
{
    // string converter from CharT to char. If CharT = char then no conversion is done.
    // if CharT is char32_t or char16_t then the conversion is UTF-32/16 -> UTF-8. Not all implementations support this yet.
    // if CharT is something else then this uses implementation defined encodings and will only work for us if the implementation uses UTF-8 as the narrow char encoding
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<CharT,char,std::mbstate_t>,CharT> convertA;

    // string converter from UTF-8 -> UTF-32. Not all implementations support this yet
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<char32_t,char,std::mbstate_t>,char32_t> convertB;

    // convert from input encoding to UTF-32 (Assuming convertA produces UTF-8 string)
    std::u32string u32input = convertB.from_bytes(convertA.to_bytes(input));

    std::basic_stringstream<CharT,traits,allocator> ss;
    ss.fill('0');
    ss << std::hex;
    for(char32_t c : u32input) {
        if(c < U'\U00010000')
            ss << convertA.from_bytes("\\u") << std::setw(4) << (unsigned int)c;
        else
            ss << convertA.from_bytes("\\U") << std::setw(8) << (unsigned int)c;
    }
    return ss.str();
}

template<typename CharT>
std::basic_string<CharT>
to_uescapes(CharT const *input)
{
    return to_uescapes(std::basic_string<CharT>(input));
}

int main() {
    std::string s = to_uescapes(u8"Hello \U00010000");
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

This should print:

> \u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\U00010000

Comment: I m not able to compile this on ubuntu  since there is no codecvt header file